# Can not track error on by bash file

Tags: linux, bash

I am new on linux, i have fedora 20 installed. when i am opening my terminal i am getting this error.

bash: export: `/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/surya/.local/bin:/home/surya/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/surya/.local/bin:/home/surya/bin=/home/surya/.node/bin/:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/surya/.local/bin:/home/surya/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/surya/.local/bin:/home/surya/bin': not a valid identifier

i can not find where is the problem

here is my .bashrc
https://docs.google.com/document/d/17VVHNdV46xTNEClOO5qsuxryIVSkyf3vqDCVcpUHYlQ/edit?usp=sharing

.bash_profile
https://docs.google.com/document/d/175hIYVmEHFTIbPEiVdLASoplSXT8uq3pD5Kq9aq-pZY/edit?usp=sharing

and in my .profile have only these two lines

PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

Answer (score 1):

Remove the path export from `~/.profile`, just provide 1 `PATH` and `export` in `~/.bashrc` as follows: `export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"` This places `/usr/local/heroku/bin` at the beginning of the existing `PATH` and will prevent the recursive exporting of `PATH` when invoking a `login` shell (see comments for discussion of sourcing `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` for `login` or `interactive` shells)

Your `.bashrc` is a mess. Do **not** source `/etc/bashrc` in your `~/.bashrc`, this is done by default and it another problem. That is the basis of one of the errors you have. So remove the `if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]` block.

The **next** error you have is how you attempt to export `$PATH` at the end of your bashrc. That is a nightmare. Get rid of the `$` following export. It should be:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH
```

That should help. Drop a comment if you still have issues.

Comment: How is it now working now? Same thing? You can see from your error that it is recursively including the path statement. That is probably due to your line: `export $PATH=$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH`. Next, you should remove your attempt to set the path in `~/.profile`. Normally, `~/.profile` is sourced on login shells (in addition to) `~/.bashrc`. Interactive shells source only `~/.bashrc`. So to eliminate recursive issues with your path, only export your path in `~/.bashrc`.